# General formula for $\int_0^1 (x-1)(x-2)\dots (x-n) dx$

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

Is there a general formula for
$$
I_n = \int_0^1 (x-1)(x-2)\dots (x-n) dx
$$
in terms of familiar sequences of number (Harmonic numbers, Bell numbers, Bernoulli numbers, etc) ?

Define
$$
P_n(x) = \int_0^x (u-1)(u-2)\dots (u-n) du
$$
Have the polynomials $P_n(x)$ appeared in the literature? Is there a simple recursive formula for $P_n(x)$? What are some interesting properties of $P_n(x)$?

The explicit formula for $P_n(x)$ can be obtained by expanding $(u-1)(u-2)\dots(u-n)$ and integrating terms by terms
$$
P_n(x) = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^{n-k+1}}{n-k+1} \sum_{1 \leq j_1 < \dots < j_k \leq n} (-1)^k j_1 j_2 \dots j_k
$$
Also, it is easy to see that
$$
P_{n+1}'(x) = (x-n-1)P'_n(x)
$$

Comment: I believe these might be the [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials_of_the_second_kind) of the second kind. [Mathworld link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumberoftheSecondKind.html).

Comment: Sorry, I meant [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3870718).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In terms of the Stirling numbers of the first kind,
$$
(x - 1) (x-2)\cdots (x - n) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {s(n,k)(x - 1)^k } .
$$
Thus,
$$
I_n  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {(-1)^k\frac{{s(n,k)}}{{k + 1}}} .
$$
Asymptotically,
$$
I_n  \sim ( - 1)^{n} \frac{{n!}}{{\log n}}
$$
as $n\to +\infty$

Comment: You need to include a factor of $(-1)^k$ in your sum for $I_n$.

Comment: Your asymptotic $I_n  \sim ( - 1)^{n - 1} \frac{{(n - 1)!}}{{\log ^2 n}}$ is very wrong. It has the wrong sign. Much better is $(-1)^n n!/\log(n)$.

Comment: @Somos Thank you for pointing out. That asymptotics was for the signless sum.